# How can I stop this CSS accordion from scrolling down automatically?

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, user-experience

I'm using an accordion made with CSS and jQuery for a site I'm making. The site also uses Bootstrap to style other parts of it.

Every time I open or close a tab the page scrolls down automatically for some reason, what should I change? Thank you all in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.accordion__trigger").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".accordion__content").toggleClass("accordion__content__hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.final__accordion {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.final__accordion .accordion__item {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.final__accordion .accordion__content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease, padding 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: height 1s ease, padding 0.3s linear;
  transition: height 1s ease, padding 0.3s linear;
}

.final__accordion .accordion__content p {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: initial;
}

.accordion__item .accordion__content {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
}

.final__accordion .accordion__content__hidden:target {
  /*CHANGED TARGET ON TOGGLE CLASSNAME*/
  height: 150px;
  text-align: left;
}

.accordion__content__hidden {
  height: 0;
}

.final__accordion .accordion__trigger {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.final__accordion .accordion__title {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(234, 10, 42);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.final__accordion .accordion__title:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.final__accordion .accordion__title:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 12px);
  right: 20px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="final__accordion" id="#accordion">
  <div class="accordion__item">
    <a href="#final__tab1" class="accordion__trigger accordion__title">Accordion 1</a>
    <div id="final__tab1" class="accordion__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor laborum, rerum quasi rem placeat quo ratione qui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion__item">
    <a href="#final__tab2" class="accordion__trigger accordion__title">Accordion 2</a>
    <div id="final__tab2" class="accordion__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor laborum, rerum quasi rem placeat quo ratione qui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion__item">
    <a href="#final__tab3" class="accordion__trigger accordion__title">Accordion 3</a>
    <div id="final__tab3" class="accordion__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor laborum, rerum quasi rem placeat quo ratione qui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion__item">
    <a href="#final__tab4" class="accordion__trigger accordion__title">Accordion 4</a>
    <div id="final__tab4" class="accordion__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor laborum, rerum quasi rem placeat quo ratione qui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion__item">
    <a href="#final__tab5" class="accordion__trigger accordion__title">Accordion 5</a>
    <div id="final__tab5" class="accordion__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor laborum, rerum quasi rem placeat quo ratione qui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion__item">
    <a href="#final__tab6" class="accordion__trigger accordion__title">Accordion 6</a>
    <div id="final__tab6" class="accordion__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor laborum, rerum quasi rem placeat quo ratione qui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share any working jsfiddle url?

Comment: Given that you're using CSS to show the accordion panels and that relies on the fragment being added to the URL (which is what is causing the scroll position to change), you can't stop this from happening without completely changing how the accordion is working

Comment: can you reproduce here - https://jsfiddle.net/79gutwma/

Comment: @ChandraPrakashVariyani why? The snippet in the question shows the problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When clicking an `<a>`nchor tag the default behavior is to jump to the location determined by `href` value. So all `<a>` have `href="#/"` which essentially prevents that jumping behavior.
2. When using jQuery you'll need to use `#id` .01% of the time and `.class` 99.99% of the time. So all `#id` are removed.
3. For animated effects like sliding there's `.slideUp/Down/Toggle()`
4. An accordion's behavior is only one section can be open at a time. So all `.content` except the `.content` that follows the clicked `.trigger` (ie. `$(this)`) will `.slideUp()`. Then the `.content` that follows the clicked `.trigger` will `.slideToggle()`.
5. `.open` is `.toggleClass()` on `.title` to animate the arrow.

BTW I removed the `.accordion__` part from all classes to save my sanity, feel free to clutter it up with `.accordion__` if you want.

```js
$(".trigger").on('click', function(e) {
  $('.title').not($(this)).removeClass('open');
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
  $('.content').not($(this).next('.content')).slideUp();
  $(this).next('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-y: scroll
}

.accordion {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.accordion .item {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.accordion .content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 150px;
}

.accordion .content p {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: initial;
}

.content.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.accordion .trigger {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion .title {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(234, 10, 42);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion .title:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.accordion .title::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 12px);
  right: 20px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transition: 0.7s;
  content: "";
}

.accordion .title.open::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#/" class="trigger title">Accordion 1</a>
    <div class="content hidden">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor laborum, rerum quasi rem placeat quo ratione qui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#/" class="trigger title">Accordion 2</a>
    <div class="content hidden">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor laborum, rerum quasi rem placeat quo ratione qui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#/" class="trigger title">Accordion 3</a>
    <div class="content hidden">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor laborum, rerum quasi rem placeat quo ratione qui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#/" class="trigger title">Accordion 4</a>
    <div class="content hidden">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor laborum, rerum quasi rem placeat quo ratione qui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#/" class="trigger title">Accordion 5</a>
    <div class="content hidden">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor laborum, rerum quasi rem placeat quo ratione qui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#/" class="trigger title">Accordion 6</a>
    <div class="content hidden">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor laborum, rerum quasi rem placeat quo ratione qui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```